# why we are calling java is a programming language and also platform

Tags: java, oracle

I've just confused and not having a clear idea to tell, **Why java is called a programming language and also a platform**. I've referred in [oracle's corporate site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html):

```
Java technology is both a programming language and a platform
```

but there is no answer for my question.

Comment: I'm not certain this question is a good fit for SO.  However, I think @SoylentGreen is correct regarding the JVM being the platform.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There's a Wikipedia entry for the "Java software platform": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28software_platform%29 Not sure if that's going to help your confusion or not.

Comment: The reason this question isn't on the Oracle site is the same reason that "Does Java start with J?" isn't there, and if you're getting hung up on stuff like this you've got a loooong road ahead of you, my friend.

Comment: That link talks separately about "the Java programming language" and "the Java platform." Seems like that answers the question about how Java is both a programming language and a platform. To clarify, "Java" is an ambiguous shorthand for either "the Java programming language" or "the Java platform," both of which are described in that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Java is not quite called a platform itself.</strike>

Java is the **programming language**.

Java runs on the **platform** called the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

**Edit**

To clarify and improve this answer following Roman Konoval's comment, the link provided by the OP (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/intro/definition.html) does indeed state

> Java technology is both a programming language and a platform.

If I am understanding the question correctly, the OP is not distinguishing a difference between the phrases "Java" and "Java technology" in the question.

Based on that interpretation (feel free to correct me) and to answer his question using his own words, "Java" (AKA, in this case, "the Java technology") encompasses everything pertaining to Java - the **programming language** itself, the JVM (the **platform**), the JDK, etc.  That is why "Java," as the OP phrases it, is, in fact, both a programming language and a platform.

Comment: You obviously didn't follow the link to oracle site, where Java is called a platform

Answer (score 1):

Java is a programming language, just read the first line here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Java runs on a platform called Java Virtual Machine, which makes it platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a programming language and it is a platform independent, because **every java program runs under the java virtual machine(jvm) platform**. The jvm is a native to the java technology. So java is both a language and also a platform.

**Note:**

**JVM is a Platform independent**, for every platform we are having different jvm's. The compiled java code is convert to the machine code for the os running which the program.

Answer (score 0):

java is a programing language not a platform. i think you are confused because of the way it is explained in the Oracle link you have mentioned.

java Programing language and the java platform(the platform on which java works) together called as JAVA TECHNOLOGY.

Java Technology = Java Programing Language + Platform it works on.

its not like java is platform. In general parlance, Java means the Java programing language.

Q: How java is Secure?
A: when we compile the java code JVM converts the java code into Byte Code, that Byte code is secure. If any changes made in that byte code it won't execute.

Comment: Please make it accepted if it helps.